# Запомнить пользователя Djabho

Tags: django

Я новичок, использую стандартную модель login в django. В settings.py прописал `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True` и `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30`, теперь при выходе из браузера нужно авторизовываться заново. Вопрос: как переписать стандартную модель login и сделать так чтобы он запоминал пользователя?

Comment: Так ведь сайт запоминает пользователя.

Comment: А зачем вы прописали SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE?

Comment: @andreymal Мне нужно чтобы изначально он не запоминал пользователя, но если отметить "запомнить меня", то уже запоминал